# How to concatenate four integers in one array in kernel?

Tags: c, linux, kernel

I have two 32-bit integers and two 16-bit integers. How can I combine them into one 12-byte long array in the kernel?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
char a[12];
char* b = &a[0];
int* c = (int*)b;
c[0] = n1;
c[1] = n2;
short* d = (short*)(b + 8);
d[0] = s1;
d[1] = s2;
```

Edit: when these statments stay in a function then there will be no strict aliasing problem.

Additionally if you want to learn more about aliasing  find this function from GCC's source: c_common_get_alias_set

Comment: `int* c = (int*)b` breaks strict aliasing and there is no guarantee `a` is even suitably aligned to be accessed via an `int*` pointer.

Comment: As I say i have considered strict aliasing. Char* will not break strict aliasing. And I have confirm that from GCC's source.

Comment: @linzuojian There are other compilers besides GCC.  You are also assuming that `int`s are 32 bits, `short`s are 16 bits, and `char`s are 8 bits.  None of these are specified in the standard.  Only minimum sizes.

Comment: @linzuojian `char*` can indeed alias `int*`, but not the other way round.

Comment: My bad. I am not sure if linux has stdint.h so I use a dirty expression.

Comment: @AhmadFatoum-a3f  After examination of GCC's source. In c_common_get_alias_set char pointer return 0 alias_set. And indirect_refs_may_alias_p compare this return value on both sides and return true when either side is 0.So it means int pointer may alias char pointer too.

Comment: @linzuojian It's not hard to avoid the aliasing problem entirely here, so why settle for a solution that might not work for future versions? Also, you didn't address the alignment issues. And having `<stdint.h>` available is a certain bet when the question is tagged Linux.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one (C99) way, if you want the machine's native byte ordering:

```
union {
  struct {
    uint32_t a, b;
    uint16_t c, d;
  } ints;
  char bytes[12];
} tmp;

tmp.ints.a = 0xdeadf00d;
tmp.ints.b = 0xfeedbabe;
tmp.ints.c = 0xfee1;
tmp.ints.d = 0x600d;
```

Now you can access the `tmp.bytes` array to get at the bytes that make up the numbers. On ideone, `bytes` contains:

```
0d f0 ad de be ba ed fe e1 fe 0d 60
```

You might want to add some (compiler-specific) padding instructions to make sure the integers are "packed", too. The above has decent alignment for many compilers, though.